# Meteor: Error: EXDEV, rename

Tags: meteor

I have just started getting this on Meteor.   It compiles perfectly on a Mac OS X system but when I upload it to a Linux system it produces the following.  Any thoughts?  Thanks :)

```
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: EXDEV, rename '/opt/meteor/src/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container'
    at Object.Future.wait (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at Object.wrapper [as rename] (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/files.js:1350:24)
    at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/files.js:810:11)
    at [object Object]._.extend.complete (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/builder.js:482:11)
    at [object Object]._.extend.saveToPath (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack.js:1075:15)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack-cache.js:236:21
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
    at [object Object]._.extend._loadLocalPackage (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack-cache.js:198:18)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack-cache.js:149:14
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
    at [object Object]._.extend._ensurePackageLoaded (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack-cache.js:141:20)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack-cache.js:63:14
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-map.js:50:7
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:87:22)
    at [object Object]._.extend.eachPackage (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-map.js:42:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend.buildLocalPackages (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack-cache.js:62:24)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/project-context.js:698:25
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
    at ProjectContext._.extend._buildLocalPackages (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/project-context.js:697:18)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/project-context.js:238:35
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
    at ProjectContext._.extend._completeStagesThrough (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/project-context.js:228:18)
    at ProjectContext._.extend.saveChangedMetadata (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/project-context.js:216:10)
    at ProjectContext._.extend.prepareProjectForBuild (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/project-context.js:221:10)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands.js:793:20
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:264:13
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:257:29
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:255:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:246:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at Object.capture (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:245:19)
    at Object.main.captureAndExit (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:271:29)
    at buildCommand (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands.js:792:8)
    at Command.main.registerCommand._.extend.name [as func] (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands.js:746:12)
    at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1363:23
    - - - - -
```

Comment: Nobody?  This is still a problem..

Comment: try to download meteor to the linux copy and just copy the files without `.meteor` files from mac ox so basically you just transfer the files without meteor copy. If this still happens it's possible you have not enough ram to run the app.

Comment: This works!  I build on Mac OS X and copied to Linux and it worked perfectly, thanks :)  Mark, it you enter this as an Answer I will Accept it for you.

Comment: hello I glad it helped! I wasn't around so posted the answer here it might help others as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the meteor local directory will do the stuff working.

```
cd $WORKDIR
rm -fr .meteor/local
```

Comment: This worked for me. Why does removing the `.meteor/local` do the trick?

Comment: In a docker environment this is solvable by adding `.meteor/local` to ones `.dockerignore` file

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to build my app for docker.

My initial Dockerfile looked something like this:

```
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN meteor build / --directory
WORKDIR /bundle/programs/server
RUN npm i
WORKDIR /bundle
RUN node main.js
```

And I kept running into the issue you described above.

After checking out a docker image for Meteor that worked, I noticed the following comment: https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord/blob/master/base/scripts/lib/build_app.sh#L6

I then modified my Dockerfile to this:

```
ADD . /app
RUN cp -R /app /tmp/app
WORKDIR /tmp/app
RUN meteor build / --directory
WORKDIR /bundle/programs/server
RUN npm i
WORKDIR /bundle
RUN node main.js
```

Which solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the files without the `.meteor` folder can help

Meteor will re-compile it on your different server/box and it should work correctly.